# Find location of desktop shortcut which invoked bash script

Tags: bash, shortcut, freedesktop.org

I have a desktop shortcut e.g `/home/user/Desktop/myfolder/link.desktop` which invokes a `bash` script located somewhere else, e.g. `/tmp/myscript.sh`

Within my script, how can I find the path of the shortcut which invoked my script? Is it possible at all?

What I actually want to achieve is that there is a subfolder where the shortcut link is, e.g. `/home/user/Desktop/myfolder/subfolder`. And in my script I would like to be able to access the subfolder.

I have tried `readlink -f` but that will always return `/home/user` no matter where the shortcut icon lies.

I cannot set the work path as the shortcut link is generated and dynamically placed in different locations.

Comment: If the shortcut link is generated, can't you have it generate an argument to your script that is the folder it resides in?

Comment: The problem is that the shortcuts are generated in one location, but then can be copied (spread) anywhere. The idea was that some input data could be accessed through the subfolder located relatively to the shortcut link.

Comment: Which desktop is it - Gnome, KDE, XFCE, ...? But then, for all of them, the directory where the shortcut is stored shouldn't play a role, but from where it is invoked, which is the Desktop.

Comment: It's KDE and yes the shortcut is invoked from the Desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well at least you can do something like this in your script:

```
find / -iname '*desktop' -exec fgrep -l $0 \{\} \; 2>/dev/null
```

That will travell your filesystem and searches every `.desktop` file for your script in it... But *note*, this can be misleading, as Someone can put comments in a `.desktop`... so you might create a searchstring first like `^Exec=/PATH/TO/$0` and use `egrep` instead of `fgrep`.

Or you can do a copy function which edits the `.desktop` files when it copies it to it's location and adds it's new location as a parameter to the `Exec` line, e.g.:

```
mycp() {
    sed "s/^Exec=.*/& $2/" $1 > $2 
}
```

Or (and I'd go with it) use the `%k` param in your `Exec` line, [according to the spec](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, but it won't work for me as I will have multiple desktop shortcuts invoking my script with different parameters

Comment: @PeterMeier updeted the answer.

Comment: Great, the param %k was what I was looking for, i can now pass %k/subfolder as parameter. Thanks!!!